# Converting List of Vectors to Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm trying to convert a list of vectors into a data frame, with there being a column for Company Names and column for the MPE. My list is generated by running the following code for each company:

```
MPE[[2]] <- c("Google", abs(((forecasted - goog[nrow(goog),]$close) 
/ goog[nrow(goog),]$close)*100))
```

Now, i'm having trouble making it into the appropriate data frame for further manipulation. What's the easiest way to do this?

This is an example list of vectors that I would want to manipulate into a dataframe with the company names in one column and the number in the second column.

```
test <- list(c("Google", 2))
test[[2]] <- c("Microsoft", 3)
test[[3]] <- c("Apple", 4)
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you could provide a reproducible example. In this case, code that would generate a list of vectors that looks like the one you want to collapse into a data frame.

Comment: Since the vectors created by `c` can only hold one type, you're coercing your numbers to strings. You can fix the issues like so: `test_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, test), stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
test_df[] <- lapply(test_df, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unlist` with `matrix` and then turn into a `dataframe`. reducing with `rbind` could take a long time with a large dataframe I think.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(test), nrow=length(test), byrow=T))
colnames(df) <- c("Company", "MPE")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to achieve what I wanted with the following:

```
MPE_df <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind ,MPE))
colnames(MPE_df) <- c("Company", "MPE")
MPE_df
```

Comment: Side note: `do.call(rbind, MPE)` is quite a bit faster than using `Reduce`